# Linking different ids through interactor

Tags: sql

I want to link different ids through the common interactor. It is bit complex but i will try my best to frame the problem.

Here are the list of steps
1. Extract id from table A.

```
Table A 

    ID   Interactor
    1   30
    2   40
```

2. Get the list of interactors corresponding to id from table B. for example,

   `select * from table B where id = 1`

Table B

```
ID   Interactors
1   30
1   32
1   33
1   36
1   38
1   39
```

3. Iterate through each interactor from the list and get the list of ids from table A.

```
Table  A    

    ID  Interactors 
    1   30
    70  32
    76  33
    Null    36
    89  38
    75  39
    2   45
    2   40
    2   43
```

4.Join these different ids so that when i select 1 i should get the below result.

`Select * where id = 1`

Result

```
    ID  Interactors 
    1   30
    70  32
    76  33
    89  38
    75  39
```

I want to achieve this using sql.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select B.ID, B.Interactors 
from A inner join B 
where A.Interactors = B.Interactors 
and A.ID = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

From step 3 you have `table A`, and before that you have `table B`.

You can use simple `inner join` with some where condition to get your desired result.

```
Select Id, Interactors from
   ( select tableA.id, tableA.Interactors 
     from tableA 
          inner join tableB 
          on tableA.Interactors = tableB.Interactors 
             and tableA.Id is not null    --- this is required since in your output record having NULL id correspond to tableA is not considered
    ) as db
where db.Id = 1    ---- you can apply any filter over there to get your desired result.
```